# InteropServices.COMException when adding item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, uwp, signalr

I using signal R core to send me a list of messages but this happen

```
public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>();

public async void InitSignalRAsync()
    {
        ChatMessage mess = new ChatMessage();
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chatHub").Build();
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            mess.user = user;
            mess.message = message;
            Messages.Add(mess);
        });
    }
```

I got an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:

at my

> Messages.Add(mess);

when I receive the data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full exception message/stack trace and if possible a [mcve].

Comment: This might be unrelated, but do you realize that you only ever have a single instance of the `ChatMessage` class? This looks really suspicous, especially since you add the same instance to the collection each time a message is received.

Comment: I need that mess object to hold the data and add it to the collection

Comment: Use a list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `Add()` must run on the UI thread when you are using `ObservableCollection`. So to make it work, make sure to execute the call in `Dispatcher.RunAsync()`:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { 
    Messages.Add(mess);
 });
```

Comment: How to use that dispatcher Martin ?

Comment: Glad it helped ;-)!

Answer (score 3):

As [Martin noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492955/263693), you must update ViewModel components from their UI thread.

However, for a solution, I recommend using the more general-purpose `SynchronizationContext` rather than the UWP-specific `Dispatcher` class. By using the more general type, your code is more reusable and more testable.

E.g.:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessage>();

public async Task InitSignalRAsync()
{
  var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chatHub").Build();
  await hubConnection.StartAsync();
  hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
  {
    var mess = new ChatMessage
    {
      user = user,
      message = message,
    };
    context.Post(_ => Messages.Add(mess));
  });
}
```

I also changed your [`async void` to `async Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (again, better reusability and testability), and made a new `ChatMessage` for each chat message, which I believe is the intended behavior.